# Can I create many DBConnections asynchronously?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, dapper

I'm trying to improve the performance of a complex database read operation. I've found some code that, in limited testing, performs much faster than previous attempts using a variety of techniques, including a hand-tuned stored procedure. It's using Dapper, but Dapper isn't the primary source of concern.

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOpenOrders(Guid vendorId)
{
    var tasks = GetAllOrders(vendorId)
        .Where(order => !order.IsCancelled)
        .Select(async order => await GetLineItems(order))
        .Select(async order =>
        {
            var result = (await order);
            return result.GetBalance() > 0M ? result : null;
        })
        .Select(async order => await PopulateName(await order))
        .Select(async order => await PopulateAddress(await order))
        .ToList();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray<Task>());
    return tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
}

private IDbConnection CreateConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection("...");
}

private IEnumerable<Order> GetAllOrders(Guid vendorId)
{
    using (var db = CreateConnection())
    {
        return db.Query<Order>("...");
    }
}

private async Task<Order> GetLineItems(Order order)
{
    using (var db = CreateConnection())
    {
        var lineItems = await db.QueryAsync<LineItem>("...");
        order.LineItems = await Task.WhenAll(lineItems.Select(async li => await GetPayments(li)));
        return order;
    }
}

private async Task<LineItem> GetPayments(LineItem lineItem)
{
    using (var db = CreateConnection())
    {
        lineItem.Payments = await db.QueryAsync<Payment>("...");
        return lineItem;
    }
}

private async Task<Order> PopulateName(Order order)
{
    using (var db = CreateConnection())
    {
        order.Name = (await db.QueryAsync<string>("...")).FirstOrDefault();
        return order;
    }
}

private async Task<Order> PopulateAddress(Order order)
{
    using (var db = CreateConnection())
    {
        order.Address = (await db.QueryAsync<string>("...")).FirstOrDefault();
        return order;
    }
}
```

This is somewhat simplified, but I hope it highlights my primary issue:

- Is this code a good idea?

I know that it's possible to make it safer by reusing the same connection, but creating many connections makes it faster by an order of magnitude in my testing. I've also tested/counted the number of concurrent connections from the database itself, and I'm seeing hundreds of statements running at the same time.

Some related questions:

- Should I use more async (ex: CreateConnection(), GetAllOrders), or
  less?
- What kind of testing can/should I do before I put this kind of
  code in production?
- Are there alternative strategies that can produce
  similar performance but require fewer connections?

Comment: rather than acquiring database connections asynchronously, have you tried specifying the Min Pool Size connection string keyword (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) so that connection pooling takes care of the grunt work?

Comment: @DanGuzman: I've played around with the connection pool options, and setting the Min Pool Size hasn't had much effect. Pooling is enabled by default as far as I can tell. If I manually set the max pool size to less than 4, performance decreases. The machine has 4 cores, so it's possible that's related. If anything, I'd be interested to know if setting the max might be a good idea to guard against potential resource issues, or if letting .Net handle it is the better option.

Comment: Note that I mentioned Min Pool Size rather than Max Pool Size.  The specified number of connection will be established automatically and added to the pool when the first connection is made.  Subsequent connections can leverage these automatically without special application code.  The downside is that these are persistent for the life of the pool.

Comment: @DanGuzman I think that is already being done, connection pooling is by default being done here, whenever a new connection is established it first checks in the connection pool and if there is a matching connection, it uses it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your computer being quad core is of no concern. There is no threading code here, this is all async code (you should learn the difference).

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi, the default connection pooling behavior will not acquire more than a single connection initially, and will physically close them after a period of inactivity.  The Min Pool spec will acquire the specified number all at once and retain them even if not reused in in short period of time.  This mitigates the initial performance hit when many connections are needed at once with burst activity.

Comment: Fyi: The throughput gains that you observe come from executing database calls in parallel. They do not come from the use of async IO or await.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that you are fetching way more data from your database than you actually need to satisfy the query.  This is known as [extraneous fetching](https://github.com/mspnp/performance-optimization/blob/master/ExtraneousFetching/docs/ExtraneousFetching.md).

Dapper is great, but unlike Entity Framework and other solutions, **it is not a LINQ provider**.  You must express the entirety of your query in the SQL, *including the `WHERE` clause*.  Dapper just helps you materialize it into objects.  It returns `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`.

So your code:

```
GetAllOrders(vendorId)
    .Where(order => !order.IsCancelled)
```

Actually requests *all* orders in the database - not just uncancelled ones.  The filter is happening in memory, afterwards.

Likewise:

```
order.Name = (await db.QueryAsync<string>("...")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The `...` of your query better include a `SELECT TOP 1`, or you will actually get all items back, just to throw away all but the first item.

Also, consider that you are making many smaller calls to populate each segment of an order.  With each order, you have 3 additional queries, with N additional rows.   This is a common anti-pattern, known as [SELECT N+1](http://google.com/search?q=select%20n%2B1).  It is *always* better to express the entirety of your query as a "chunky" operation than to emit many chatty queries to the database.  This is also described as the [chatty I/O anti-pattern](https://github.com/mspnp/performance-optimization/blob/master/ChattyIO/docs/ChattyIO.md).

With regards to the async questions - while there is nothing inherently wrong with making multiple database calls in parallel, that's not exactly what you're doing here.  Since you're awaiting each step along the way, you're still doing things serially.

Well, at least you're doing them serially for each order.  You are getting *some* parallelism in the outer loop.  But all of the inner stuff is essentially serial.  The `Task.WaitAll` will block until all of the outer tasks (one per order filtered) are complete.

Another problem is that you aren't in an async context when you call `GetOpenOrders` in the first place.  The real benefits of async/await aren't realized until you have [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) up and down the stack. I also suggest you watch [this video series on async from Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async).

My recommendation is to:

- Determine the full query you need to run to retrieve all the data from the database, but not more than you actually need.
- Execute that query in Dapper.  Use `Query` if you're in a synchronous context (`IEnumerable<Order> GetOpenOrders`), or use `QueryAsync` if you're in an asynchronous context (`async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> GetOpenOrdersAsync`).  Don't try to use the async query from a non-async context.
- Use Dapper's [multi-mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) feature to retrieve multiple objects from a single query.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. Dapper's multi-mapping certainly helps, though putting together multiple one-to-many relationships adds some unfortunate complexity. In any case, I could tell there were some code smells here, and I greatly appreciate you pointing me to the descriptions of what exactly they are.